# C: get first character of d_name

Tags: c, file, struct, directory

Just wondering, given the following code code snippet

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <sys/types.h>
#include    <dirent.h>

void do_ls(char []);

main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    if ( ac == 1 )
        do_ls( "." );
    else
        while ( --ac ){
            printf("%s:\n", *++av );
            do_ls( *av );
    }
}

void do_ls( char dirname[] )



{
    DIR     *dir_ptr;       /* the directory */
    struct dirent   *direntp;       /* each entry    */

    if ( ( dir_ptr = opendir( dirname ) ) == NULL )
        fprintf(stderr,"ls1: cannot open %s\n", dirname);
    else
     {
        while ( ( direntp = readdir( dir_ptr ) ) != NULL )
            printf("%s\n", direntp->d_name[0] );
        closedir(dir_ptr);
    }
}
```

Instead of getting the whole name of each entry, how do I get a specific character of each entry (for example the first character in the name) instead of the whole name. In the code I tried to use `direntp->d_name[0]` but it didn't work.

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler warn you on something being not good here: `printf("%s\n", direntp->d_name[0] );`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `%s` to `%c` in your `printf`, this will print a character.

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <sys/types.h>
#include    <dirent.h>

void do_ls(char []);

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    if ( ac == 1 )
        do_ls( "." );
    else {
        while ( --ac ) {
            printf("%s:\n", *++av );
            do_ls( *av );
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void do_ls( char dirname[] )
{
    DIR     *dir_ptr;       /* the directory */
    struct dirent   *direntp;       /* each entry    */

    if ( ( dir_ptr = opendir( dirname ) ) == NULL )
        fprintf(stderr,"ls1: cannot open %s\n", dirname);
    else
    {
        while ( ( direntp = readdir( dir_ptr ) ) != NULL )
            printf("%c\n", direntp->d_name[0] );
        closedir(dir_ptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: "*this*": what?

Comment: @JoeKur yes, something like `if (direntp->d_name[0] == 't') `

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
printf("%s\n", direntp->d_name[0] );
```

to be

```
printf("%c\n", direntp->d_name[0]);
```

[From the C11 Standard (draft)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8):

> **7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function**
>
> [...]
>
> 8 The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> `c` [...] the int argument is converted to an
>   unsigned char, and the resulting character is written. [...]
>
> `s` [...] the argument shall be a pointer to the initial
>   element of an array of character type.280) Characters from the array are
>   written up to (but not including) the terminating null character. [...]